# Ways of inserting a + sign in latex (package menukeys)

Tags: menukeys

I have a problem with a + sign. I use package "menukeys" and if i write down a command `\keys{Eclipse C++ Development tool}` the package keys will split my command analogous to three key commands: `\keys{Eclipse C} \keys{} \keys{Development tool}`

Is there any different way of inserting plus sign into latex?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put `Eclipse C++ Development tool` inside a group. See subsection 4.1 of the `menukeys` documentation:

> You can hide a separator from the parser by putting a part of the sequence in braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{Eclipse C++ Development tool}

\keys{{Eclipse C++ Development tool}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A checkmark is nothing compared to time you spent for anwsering my question. Thank you.